# AngularJS - Getting all keys from an object

Tags: angularjs

I want to be able to get all the keys from an object. Assuming the object looks like below:

```
            this.reservation = {
            "Firstname" : "" ,
            "Lastname" :"" ,
            "Phone" : "",
            "Email" : "",
            "Date" : "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm",
            "Starthour" : "",
            "Endhour" : "",
            "Persons" : ""
        }
```

If I want to be able to check whether all the keys' values are `""`, except `Date` of course, how would I go about doing that?

I've tried to do a `forEach` to get the keys:

```
            angular.forEach(this.reservation,
            function(value, key) {
                console.log(key);
            });
```

But it doesn't work. Any hints?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this,

```
Object.keys(reservation);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object.keys and some functional Array methods

```
var allEmptyExceptDate = Object.keys(this.reservation)
  .filter(function(key) { return key !== 'Date'; }) // all except 'Date'
  .every(function(key) { return !this.reservation[key] })  // are falsy (i.e. empty or undefined or null) - or you can use this.reservation[key] === '' for a more precise check
```

Answer (score 0):

For objects you can use the **for in** loop

Pure javascript way of doing this:

```
for(prop in this.reservation){ 
    if(typeof this.reservation[prop] === "string"){
         console.log(prop + 'value ' + "is a string");
    } 
}
```

Angular way:

```
angular.forEach(this.reservation, function(value, key){
    if(typeof value === "string"){
        console.log(value + ' is of type string');
    }
}
```

Comment: Urm.. `angular.forEach` can **definitely** iterate through objects.